# Create a column with numbers from 0 to 1000 in increments of 10

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to google sheets and am unaware of how to create a sequence of numbers in a column. I want to create a column with numbers from 0 to 1000 in increments of 10

Comment: The question is too broad. What kind of solution are you looking for (formula, script, something else)? Have you already mad any effort to figured out how to achieve the result you are looking for? Ref. [ask].

Comment: Hello, I am looking for a formula. I have researched throughout the internet but to no avail, if you have any useful links as well that would be nice. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer. Also add a brief description of your search/research efforts.

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1 (formula)

1. Copy the following formula `=(ROW()-1)*10`
2. Select cells `A1:A100`
3. Paste the formula.

## Method 2 (fill down series):

1. Write `0` on `A1`
2. Write `10` on `A2`
3. Write `20` on `A3`
4. Select `A1:A3`
5. Click on the bottom right corner of `A3`, then drag down until `A100`.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({0; ROW(A1:A100)&0})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({0\ ROW(A1:A100)&0})
```

[image]

---

if you want real numbers then use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({0; VALUE(ROW(A1:A100)&0)})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({0\ VALUE(ROW(A1:A100)&0)})
```

[image]